# URL to PDF Solution

Tags: python, pdf, url, png, screenshot

How can i pass this URL to PDF?
Im trying with the below code, but doesnt work
I tried with URL to PNG, or screenshot of a page, but doesnt work, just generate an empty pdf/image

Any solution?

The url:
http://windte1910.acepta.com/v01/0EF57BFD40060E245941AE43E3F7DAB700A06338

Code:

```
import pdfkit

path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path_wkthmltopdf)

pdfkit.from_url("http://windte1910.acepta.com/v01/0EF57BFD40060E245941AE43E3F7DAB700A06338", "out2.pdf", configuration=config)
```

Output:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: A finished ResourceObject received a loading progress signal. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Warning: A finished ResourceObject received a loading finished signal. This might be an indication of an iframe taking too long to load.
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                      
True
```

Comment: which is your SO ?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Windows 10

Comment: I found some ...the problem is that the web have a iframe ..for example if you reaplce the url with this http://windte1910.acepta.com/ca4webv3/index.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwindte1910.acepta.com%2Fv01%2F0EF57BFD40060E245941AE43E3F7DAB700A06338  , this work ...

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar Thanks, this works!! but in the url show me something like this: %3A%2F%2F , is there a way to replace this with :// ?

Comment: I answered below ...you can use https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ for decode/encode the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found is that the web has an iframe, so it appears blank ... if you change that url for this one

http://windte1910.acepta.com/ca4webv3/index.jsp?url=http://windte1910.acepta.com/v01/0EF57BFD40060E245941AE43E3F7DAB700A06338

then it will work ... if you have knowledge in html / css , check the google chrome console you will find it, maybe you should consider scraping to get the content of the iframe using beautifulSoup

```
import pdfkit

path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path_wkthmltopdf)

#pdfkit.from_url("http://windte1910.acepta.com/v01/0EF57BFD40060E245941AE43E3F7DAB700A06338", "out2.pdf", configuration=config)
pdfkit.from_url("http://windte1910.acepta.com/ca4webv3/index.jsp?url=http://windte1910.acepta.com/v01/0EF57BFD40060E245941AE43E3F7DAB700A06338", "out2.pdf", configuration=config)
```